# Is this rearrangement correct? Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Solve for Y:** $$P_x\left(\frac{I}{P_x} - a\right) + P_yY = I$$

Answer: $$Y = \frac{a}{P_y}$$

Note: - a in the question isn't in the denominator in case it's confusing typed out like this.

Thanks!

Comment: The lack of clarity can be resolved by using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  You are likely to get more positive results if you, at the very least, make the effort to make your notation readable.

Comment: You've asked a lot of these questions recently. Why don't try running the question through [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+P_x+(I+%2F+P_x+-+a)+%2B+P_y+Y+%3D+I+for+Y) instead, and working out how it got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. Note $P_x \left( \frac{I}{P_x} - a\right) + P_yY = I \implies  I - P_xa + P_yY = I \implies P_xa = P_yY$.

Comment: Right, thanks for the response! Just to add: originally, it was $$PxX + PyY = I$$ I solved for X, and then inserted this into that equation, which is what I posted here. However, I assumed you put brackets when you do this. Was I right to do so? Does it change the answer at all? Essentially, my value for X was: $$I/Px - a$$

Comment: @MathsHelp No, the answer does not change.